# Arch install - Can't install GRUB

Tags: arch-linux, grub, gpt, uefi

I'm currently trying to install arch linux alongside windows 10 on my computer which is UEFI and formatted as a GPT partition table. However, when installing grub using the command:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=esp --bootloader-id=grub
```

This returns

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: esp doesn't look like an EFI partition.
.
```

Before doing this I had created 3 partitions on my hard-drive, alongside two windows partitions. I used cgdisk to create a 2gb EFI system partition, a 4gb Linux Swap partition, a 91gb Linux filesystem partition.

I entered the commands

```
mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sda3 (the efi partition)
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt (the linux filesystem)
mount /dev/sda3 /boot (to mount the efi partition in /boot as reccomended)
```

Then installing grub and efibootmgr, I get the errors listed above.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, when I made the drive a fat32, I had /dev/sda3. I'm sure I've booted into UEFI because there is an option to boot into just the "disk" or "UEFI: Disk". As for the name I thought that was just what I had to enter as the command but I also checked --efi-directory=/boot and --efi-directory=/boot/efi.

Comment: If Windows is already installed, you should already have an ESP (surely /dev/sda1), also there's no need for grub with UEFI, use systemd-boot instead.

Comment: I have an SSD for windows 10 and I use the hard drive to store games, etc, which I want to use for arch. Would this still work?

Comment: 2gb for /boot/efi is a tad too much if you don't intend to store huge kernel+initrd pile there forever, 100mb is more than enough for a bootloader these days :)
simple `grub-install` should suffice, and it will run `efibootmgr` for you as well.
see also http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this part: `--efi-directory=esp`.

You should not put “`esp`” as it is only a place holder for the directory that holds EFI.

Assuming that EFI is contained in `/boot`. In this case this part of the line will read:

```
--efi-directory=/boot
```